# Android - Issue with scrollview

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview

I am using scrollview on my activity. The scrollview contains a LinearLayout and some other views inside that layout. There is another LinearLayout `android:id="@+id/linLayoutImagesContainer"` used to put images items with 3 images dynamically just like in Gridview with three columns.
All other things are working perfectly. But, If I add more than 12 rows (i,e.36 images) into LinearLayout dynamically then the scrollview becomes blank with no view.
Can anybody help me? Thanks in advance.

**My xml layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relLayoutActionBar"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="@drawable/background_action_bar">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Activity Detail"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="20sp"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivButtonBack"
        android:layout_width="35dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/back_icon"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="14sp"/>
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relLayoutTripBanner"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/relLayoutActionBar">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewActivityBanner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="220dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:background="@drawable/default_activity_banner"/>

    <!--<Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonActivityBanner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:background="@null"/>-->
</RelativeLayout>

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/parallaxScroll"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/relLayoutActionBar"
    android:layout_above="@+id/relLayoutActionFooter">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingTop="220dp">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonActivityBanner"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="220dp"
            android:background="@null"
            android:layout_marginTop="-220dp"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="#ffffffff"
            android:alpha="0.9">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewTripDescription"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:alpha="0.9"
                android:background="#ffffffff"
                android:text="Activity (Description)"
                />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"

                android:background="@drawable/layout_round_border">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textViewImages"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="35dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Images (0)"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:background="@drawable/layout_left_round_colored"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/viewDate"
                    />

                <View
                    android:id="@+id/viewDate"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="60dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textViewVideos"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="35dp"
                    android:layout_alignEnd="@id/textViewImages"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Videos (0)"
                    android:textColor="#ffec6221"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/viewDate"/>
            </RelativeLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linLayoutImagesContainer"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp">
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: can you try calling requestLayout() once you are done adding your images.Call requestLayout after every image add if needed.

And please add (to this question)the code you are using to dynamically add the image views too

Comment: If you review the logcat, do you see a high usage of memory and possibly an exception, or is there nothing related there?

Comment: @Shade23 I have called requestLayout() but its not working.

Comment: Post the code how you add view to the LinearLayout and also the layout of those views

Comment: I have solved my issue. Its due to alpha=0.9 on linear layout and its textview. I have removed alpha.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relLayoutActionBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@drawable/background_action_bar">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Activity Detail"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="20sp"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivButtonBack"
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/back_icon"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="14sp"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relLayoutTripBanner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageViewActivityBanner"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="220dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:background="@drawable/default_activity_banner"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/parallaxScroll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingTop="220dp">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonActivityBanner"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="220dp"
                android:background="@null"
                android:layout_marginTop="-220dp"/>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:background="#ffffffff"
                android:alpha="0.9">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textViewTripDescription"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:alpha="0.9"
                    android:background="#ffffffff"
                    android:text="Activity (Description)"
                    />

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="35dp"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"

                    android:background="@drawable/layout_round_border">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textViewImages"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="35dp"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="Images (0)"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                        android:background="@drawable/layout_left_round_colored"
                        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/viewDate"
                        />

                    <View
                        android:id="@+id/viewDate"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="60dp"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textViewVideos"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="35dp"
                        android:layout_alignEnd="@id/textViewImages"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="Videos (0)"
                        android:textColor="#ffec6221"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/viewDate"/>
                </RelativeLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/linLayoutImagesContainer"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp">
                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```